# how to determine which version of gtk+ I have on centos?

Tags: gtk

I'm using centos, I'm wondering what is the correct way to determine the version of my gtk.
I searched and found some methods but they gave different answers, so I'm confused. For example:
My centos has this directory:

> /usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/2.10.0

, so the version is 2.10.0.
But "

> pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0

" gave "2.18.9".
And "

> rpm -qa | grep -i gtk2

" shows:

```
gtk2-devel-2.18.9-12.el6.x86_64
gtk2-engines-2.18.4-5.el6.centos.x86_64
gtk2-2.18.9-12.el6.x86_64
gtk2-immodule-xim-2.18.9-12.el6.x86_64
```

I'm totally confused. Anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: `gtk-launch --version` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of GTK is the one of your `gtk2-2.x.x-y.el6.x86_64` (that is, 2.18.9), and also given by pkg-config.

(`gtk-engines` probably has a lower version because it may not have released micro versions 5 through 9. The other answer, 2.10.0, is an API version for GTK's modules. That directory separates that format of GTK modules from GTK 3.0 modules, for example.)